# built in Abstract Data Types in c++/python/java

Tags: java, c++, python, c

I was until now programming in C, which is a very basic language. But now as I am studying data structures, my online teacher actually uses some methods like leftChild(), rightChild(), etc.
But then I started searching whether tree ADT and such are implemented in C++, Python, Java 
by default. And mostly the answers were no.

I just want to confirm whether any language supports tree ADT by default that means without downloading their classes separately.

Comment: C++ uses a more abstract interface than `tree`. It uses `searchable container` and `set`.

Comment: does c++ contain methods for directly using trees or any other language has this facility by default installation of its compiler without any further downloads

Comment: As I said, the interface is more abstract the `tree`. The interface may or may not be implemented using a `tree`. But, the implementation of the interface is provided as part of the standard C++ library, mostly in the STL.

Comment: A plain non-balanced tree is not a very useful data structure you can easily make yourself. The languages you mention do support data structures based on balanced binary search (usually red-black) trees. Java has, for instance, TreeMap and TreeSet.

Comment: @AardvarkSoup: it is a very useful DS. tree != search tree.

Comment: @user1139048: why do you asked this question? why do you care whether it's a builtin / part of the standard library?

Comment: Tree and any other complicated data structure are not part of programming language feature. To keep compiler simple and efficient. And provided by library features.

Answer (score -1):

Many of the STL containers in C++ are commonly implemented using trees. Examples include `std::map` and `std::set`

Answer (score -1):

These are the basic ADTs. I think you should first learn and code them yourselves before jumping into any library with these inbuild features.

Thanks